# Unable to access Flower on Docker with either Redis or Rabbitmq

Tags: docker, redis, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I am trying to build a Python scheduler using celery beat and flower on Docker. both the worker tasks and flower work perfectly fine when I run them on my local machine. But when I use Docker to implement this, my tasks run fine but I just cannot open Flower on the browser. I don't see any error as it starts up in the logs but for some reason, localhost:5555 just gives me nothing.

This is my docker-compose.yml file using rabbitmq

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:latest

  worker:
    image: celery_simple:latest
    entrypoint: celery -A tasks worker -B --loglevel=INFO 
    depends_on:
      - rabbit

  flower:
    image: celery_simple:latest    
    command: ["flower", "-A", "tasks", "--address=0.0.0.0", "--broker=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/","--port=5555", "--logging=DEBUG"]
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

and using Redis:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01
    ports:
     - '6379:6379'

  worker:
    image: celery_simple:latest
    entrypoint: celery -A tasks worker -B --loglevel=INFO
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    image: celery_simple:latest 
    image : flower:latest
    command: ["flower", "--address=0.0.0.0", "--broker=redis://redis:6379","--port=5555", "--logging=DEBUG"]
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Comment: Did you try with added `ports: 5555:5555` for for flower?

Comment: Yes, I believe this worked. Thank you